# How do I trigger an NSURLAuthenticationChallenge with NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, foundation

I can't find any documentation on `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm`. How do I trigger an `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` with an `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm` `authenticationMethod`?

More specifically, is there any way to induce the URL Loading system to produce a challenge like that based on a response from an HTTP server? Or is `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTMLForm` only for synthetic authentication challenges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't divulge the source, but I asked someone that would know, and they said:

> This challenge is never generated by Foundation.  It is used for
>   credential persistence